# Tips about trying to get tree sapling to grow after winter fallout

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, seedlings

[image]I sprouted this sapling from seed in my backyard, and it grew to a foot tall with 2 big leaves in 2 months. But winter came and it stunted its growth, and the top part of the stem dried up. Now it is getting warmer, and I am wondering if there is anything I can do to allow it to grow, as the leaves are still mostly green, the stem is green and intact, and the roots are still intact. I am in hardiness zone 10, and the tree is a jackfruit tree.